# ABC synthesis - read_liberty

Tags: yosys

I'm using abc01008.exe to synthesize combinational functions.
I have been using mcnc.genlib and stdcell.lib with no problems.

I would like to use a different std_cell libray that is in the liberty format.
When I type 'rty' or 'read_liberty' I do get the following error:

abc 01> rty
** cmd error: unknown command 'read_liberty'
(this is likely caused by using an alias defined in "abc.rc"
without having this file in the current or parent directory)
abc 01> read_liberty
** cmd error: unknown command 'read_liberty'
(this is likely caused by using an alias defined in "abc.rc"
without having this file in the current or parent directory)

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thx in advance

Comment: Where did this abc come from? If you run 'help', do you see read_liberty in the list of available commands?

Comment: I do not see it in the list of commands. But it is in the abc.rc list of commands and in a power point presentation that talks about it. So I'm wondering how to make it work.